# Does the noun "Kärtchen" have a plural form?

Tags: noun, german-to-english

My dictionary does not even have the word `Kärtchen`, and online translators have very little about this noun. I think that it's neuter (das), yet I would like to know if this word has a plural form and if so, how it is spelled.

Comment: I like to refer to http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/abfrage/ which has a complete declination for "kärtchen", listed after "Flexion".

Answer (score 23):

One reason you are having difficulties finding an adequate dictionary entry is because **Kärtchen** is what is known as a diminutive form. One of the diminutive endings *-chen* or *-lein*, when added to nouns, makes the modified noun smaller, cuter, or (less often) laughable. (Unfortunately for many words one of the two diminutives is much more common than the other, but there is no easy rule for it.)

Take for example:

> Das Tierchen (the little animal)
>   Das Brötchen (small bread, here: a roll)
>   Das Häuschen (the little house)

You'll notice that all the diminutives are assigned the neuter (das) article. Additionally, all diminutive forms remain the same in the plural as their singular. Thus,

> Die Tierchen (the little animals)
>   Die Brötchen (the rolls)
>   Die Häuschen (the little houses)

In the case of **Kärtchen**, this is the diminutive form of *die Karte*. As you can see, some vowels (a, o, and u) become the umlauted diphthongs (ä, ö, ü) when the diminutive is made. Additionally, nouns ending in *-e* often (but not always) drop this letter. Both of the above morphological phenomena can be seen in the example of **die Karte -> das Kärtchen**.

Following the above rule regarding the pluralization of diminutives, its plural is *die Kärtchen*. Since every noun has a possible diminutive form, most are left out of the dictionary. The only ones that are found in the dictionary are typically ones with concrete meanings such as Brötchen, Mädchen (girl), etc.

**Note:**
Not every word that ends in the letters *chen* is a diminutive variant, as Alexander has pointed out in the comments. A few examples:

> Eichen (oak trees)
>   **BUT** Eichen (little egg[s]) from *Ei + chen*
>   Aachen (a city in Germany)

There are other diminutive forms depending on dialect as well. These are explained in more detail in this [English-language Wikipedia article,](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) as well as this [German-language Wiki article](http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutiv).

Comment: bisschen! -----

Comment: Ei -> Eichen? ;)

Comment: @Carlster Good point, not sure that this is the right place to get into indefinite pronouns though.

Comment: I think a, o and u becoming umlauts and the dissapearing vowels at the end are dictionary-relevant, too.

Comment: But the diminutive form of "das Ei" is "das Eichen", right? And it is pronounced exactly like "das Eichen" an "Eichamt" (Office of Weights and Measures) does, and also "die Eichen" are pronounced the same.

Comment: @Carlster Agreed, I'll add some more info when I get to my desk.

Comment: @Alexander I wouldn't pronounce das Eichen (kleines Ei) the same as die Eichen (Bäume). Perhaps this is a regional thing? Or a mistake on my part, as I'm not a native speaker. Cf: Eichhörnchen: first ch pair is much harder than the diminutive ending..

Comment: Use Brötchen only in Germany, not in Austria.

Comment: I only know two types of pronunciation for ch: the hard one like in "Rachen" or "Buchen", and the softer one like in "Milchgesicht" ;) or "Eichen". Of course there may be regional differences, Germany is a country of regional differences.

Comment: @Alexander Because it is unclear if there is a pronunciation difference between the two, I've removed reference to such in my answer.

Comment: "Mädchen" always makes me wonder if the base thereof is really "Made" (and indeed in the Ore Mountains they say "Mad"). But I guess this originally rather stems from something like "Magd". Maybe this would make an interesting question on its own (if there isn't one already).

Comment: @Alexander There are also the ones that are spoken like a "k", but those are rather rare and in special constellations, like "Fuchs", or in some regions at the start of words ("Chemie", "China").

Comment: Yet, I've never actively used or heard someone use the diminutive of "Ei" ever, though would indeed pronounce it like the trees (or like "Eichhörnchen" for that matter).

Comment: @Christian I'm starting to wonder if my pronunciation distinction between Eichen (eggs) and Eichen (oaks) is influenced by Swabian dialect, or simply my own non-native quirks...

Comment: But then there's [this](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_%28Digraph%29), which would imply that there is a difference in pronunciation between Eichen (oaks) and Eichen (little egg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16381/discussion-between-milchgesicht-and-christian-rau).

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gaertchen)You can use [Kärtchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kaertchen) in singular and plural.
It´s a [diminutive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) form. In german it´s a [Diminutiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutiv) (Verniedlichungsform, Verkleinerungsform)

This form is build from a noun and a suffix like: -lein, -chen, -ette, -erl.

The word [Kärtchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kaertchen) comes from [Karte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Karte)
Singular: `die Karte`   ==> `das Kärtchen`
Plural:     `die Karten` ==> `die Kärtchen`

---

One approximation to get the root word:

- Remove -lein, -chen, -erl, -ette from the end of the word.
- Replace ä with a, ü with u, ö with o and ß with s.
  If the word is a "zusammengesetztes Hauptwort" only replace the letters of the "Hauptwort" at the end.
- Add -e, -er, -en or nothing to the end of the word.

This does not cover all possibilities.

---

Examples:

[Kärtchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kaertchen) to [Karte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Karte)
1.) Kärt  (After removing the -chen)
2.) Kart  (After replacing ä with a)
3.) Karte (After adding -e)

[Häuschen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haeuschen) to [Haus](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus)
1.) Häus (After removing -chen)
2.) Haus (After replacing ä with a)

[Kräutergärtchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gaertchen) to [Kräutergarten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kraeutergarten)
1.) Kräutergärt (After removing -chen)
2.) Kräutergart (After replacing ä of the last Hauptwort with a)
3.) Kräutergarten (After adding -en)

[Märchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maerchen) to [Mär](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maer):
1.) Mär (After removing the -chen)

[Stiefelette](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stiefelette) to [Stiefel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stiefel)
1.) Stiefel (After removing the -ette)

[Weckerl](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weckerl) to [Wecken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wecken_Semmel_Brot_Backwerk)
1.) Weck (After removing the -erl)
2.) Wecken (After adding -en)

[Eichhörnchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eichhoernchen) to [Eichhorn](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eichhorn)
1.) Eichhörn (After removing the -chen)
2.) Eichhorn (After replacing the ö with o)

---

An example where this approximation is wrong:

[Mädchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maedchen) to [Magd](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Magd):
1.) Mäd (After removing the -chen)
2.) Mad (After replacing the ä with a)
3.) You cant get to Magd by adding something to the end.

Comment: Maybe you want to give the OP tips on how to identify the root word.